# telegram.ext shown unavailable even after installing python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a telegram bot using python, although when I am importing from telegram.ext PyCharm says that it can not find .ext in the telegram package.
And yes I have installed all required dependancies as far as the one's I know of.

```
from telegram.ext  import *
```

Please do have a look at my pip freeze to see if I missed any?

```
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2022.9.24
python-telegram-bot==13.14
pytz==2022.6
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
six==1.16.0
telegram==0.0.1
tornado==6.1
tzdata==2022.7
tzlocal==4.2
```

Another thing that might be important is that is is a completely fresh venv with just the 2 packages and requisite dependancies.

Help would be much appreciated.

I have also tried creating a fresh venv and and reinstalling the said libraries `telegram` and `python-telegram-bot` but that did not help either.

Comment: `pip freeze` execute in the venv?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold It does! Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have installed the [telegram library](https://pypi.org/project/telegram/) which has nothing to do with `python-telegram-bot` and doesn't actually contain any useful code. You should uninstall it via `pip uninstall telegram -y` and then re-install `python-telegram-bot`.

FYI: https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/1252

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telgeram-bot`

Comment: Hey I created a new virtual env and just installed python-telegram-bot still doesn't work, I have version 13.15 installed as per pip freeze.

Comment: The problem is not that PTB is not installed, the problem is that `telegram` is installed as well. Make sure that `telegram` is not installed.